# How one vector space can have more than one basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

What I know is that a  basis contains the maximum number of linearly independent vectors in the vector space that spans the vector space and the # of basis vectors is the dimension of the vector space, if a vector space have two basis then wouldn't  the dimension of vector space change?

Comment: The vectors in the basis may change, but the NUMBER of vectors in the basis does not.

Comment: If the two basis have the same number of elements then the dimension is the same what confirms the fact that the dimension is well defined. In general a basis of a vectorial space is not unique, take your favorite vectorial space $V$, take $x \ne 0$ and consider the spanned space $W$. Then any $\lambda x$, $\lambda \ne 0$, span the space $W$.

Comment: $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^2$, but clearly also $e_1$ and $e_1+e_2$. So of course there are several bases for one given non-trivial vector space.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for some intuition, then try to think like this : Think of 3-dimensional (euclidean) space. This is a vector space with respect to $\mathbb{R}$. There are infinitely many ways to define a coordinate axis with the origin unchanged, for this. Especially any rotation of the original coordinate system gives us a new coordinate system. The unit vectors along the original coordinate axes is a basis whereas the unit vectors along the new axes is another basis. Since there are many (infinitely many) ways (angles) to rotate the axes, there are infinitely many bases possible even though number of dimensions remain 3.

PS: I am not claiming that the axes obtained by rotation are the only bases for $\mathbb{R}^3$. In fact it is not. It is much more richer than that. Any collection of vectors obtained from the original axes by a bijective transformation- such as rotation, reflection, or 'squeezing' are all other bases.

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider some practical situations where a chance of basis doesn't change the dimension. Using $\mathbb{R}^3$ to model the usual three dimensional space. This happens in practice when we change units of measure, say from meter to centimeters. Something that was at the point $(1,0,0)$ when measured in meters is now at the point $(100,0,0)$ in centimeters and likewise for the other axes. Now the units we measured in are arbitrary and don't change the dimension of the space even though they change the coordinates we measured them in.

Another arbitrary choice is what direction the axes point in. Someone south of the equator might orient up to be south while someone on the north side might choose north for up. They didn't change the dimension of the space by choosing a different direction to measure in. In fact we don't even have to have the axes at right angles to each other. Say for example we tilt the canonical basis vectors a small distance towards their center of mass. While the basis is now skew we can still map out any point in three dimensions using these frame.

So while we change the basis vectors we don't change the space in which they exist and so the dimension stays the same. The dimension of the space tells us that we need so many vectors to uniquely identify each point with a unique coordinate. If we don't have enough we can't get to every point and if we have too many some of them are redundant. The dimension formalizes this geometric notion algebraically so that it can be calculated in other spaces that might not behave in the same way as $\mathbb{R}^3$ but still give us so me idea about how many coordinates we need to label every point in the space.